# Adjust UI Element for iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, size-classes

I have edited this question so that I can first get the basics.

In the simplest of terms I need a UI element to scale to the different screen sizes. I need this white view to remain with a size that scales and continues to be positioned so that it looks same regardless of screen size.
[image]

When I preview the above the white view is off centre and misshaped.
I just want it looking same in all screen sizes but scaled accordingly. How can I achieve something that surely should be so simple?

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: and how do I position that in the view? Im editing the question to get back to basics.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you a great tool named [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry.).

> Harness the power of AutoLayout NSLayoutConstraints with a simplified, chainable and expressive syntax. Supports iOS and OSX Auto Layout

Sample code the lib offers, it's just what you want:

```
UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
  make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top); //with is an optional semantic filler
  make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
  make.bottom.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
  make.right.equalTo(superview.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
}];

// Or even shorter

[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
  make.edges.equalTo(superview).with.insets(padding);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link you posted to Masonry doesn't work so I can not explore your answer. Im also hoping to do the layout in storyboard if possible.

Comment: @RyanForsyth it's okay, i just offer u a good choice, so u won't meet this issue any more in the feature. And sorry that i cannot offer any help for storyboard, i don't use it. :)